# Render Angular components in different parts of the root template

Tags: angular, templates, frontend

Given the following Angular view:

```
  <accordion>
    <accordion-item heading="Item #1">
      The content of the first menu item #1 goes here...
    </accordion-item>
    <accordion-item heading="Item #2">
      <other-component>
      </other-component>
    </accordion-item>
    <accordion-item heading="Item #3">
      The content of the third menu item #3 goes here...
    </accordion-item>
  </accordion>
```

How can I render template of the accordion-item component in one part of template of the accordion component and whatever is inside the accordion-item in other part of the root template?

```
// the accordion template
<div class="accordion accordion-container">
  <div class="items-menu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
      <accordion-item [heading]="item.heading"> </accordion-item>
    </ng-container>
  </div>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    ... The children of accordion-item are being rendered here ...
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I render template of the accordion-item component ? What does this mean. ? It's quite confusing.

Comment: I have to move somehow whatever components or even pure text inside <accordion-item> to a specific place in the template of <accordion> to be rendered. It's sort of you detach children components from its parent and render them separately in the root template.

Comment: Root template , means which one ? Give one example.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this very good tutorial (for tabs, but this is the same principle), which recommend to use the `QueryList` feature of Angular:

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/learning-ng2-creating-tab-component/

You can reach children components of type `AccordionItemComponent` by using:

```js
@ContentChildren(AccordionItemComponent) items: QueryList<AccordionItemComponent>;
```